Should I use a cover letter for my writing samples in my PhD application?
I can't find any guidelines regarding this. For context I'm applying to one of Stanford's graduate program. Assuming that a cover page would be fine, if not required, would such a basic cover page be okay? My MA thesis is my best work, but it was way too long, which I then condensed into an article and is currently under blind-PR. I've decided to use some of its parts as the writing sample as I'll be able to include more content overall. Want to know that if mentioning the same in the cover page, and cover page in general would be a good idea, or should I just submit it with no context. Also should I include appendices and works cited section in the writing sample? That'd increase the number of pages considerably.


Provided that the institution permits it, I would prefer to see a brief explanation in cases in which the sample is an excerpt from a larger work. Others might differ.
The purpose of such a sample is to get a general idea of your writing competence, especially within the field if possible. It goes a bit beyond familiarity with the language itself.
And, no, the appendices and bibliography aren't essential for this purpose.
And, you might consider an excerpt from a published work or thesis, rather than a separate condensation.
